# How do you display a variable that is changing in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to make a game where you are able to do damage to an enemy and he can do damage back. I want to display his health whenever someone is attacked. Here is what I have:

```
    TextView playerhealth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlayerHealth); 
        playerhealth.setText("Player Health:" + player_health);
    TextView enemyhealth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EnemyHealth); 
        enemyhealth.setText("Enemy Health:" + enemyone_health);
```

However, the text does not update when damage is done and I do not know how to fix this. Could someone please help?

Comment: Where are you using the code you posted? Is it being used each time the `player_health` variable is changed?

Comment: Incomplete question. Its like saying that System.out.println("1") ; is not printing.

Comment: Print variable which is changed instead of `TextView` Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're setting the text immediately after finding the TextView meaning that you overwrite the original value immediately.

You need to find the TextView, then do something which damages your Player/Enemy and then update the TextView with the new value you're left with.

Try setting a value, then sleeping for a few seconds, then applying it to your TextView and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing set text to you text view just after the variable value is changed

Like:

player_health = **your manipulation to the variable** and then

```
playerhealth.setText("Player Health:" + player_health);
```

enemyone_health = **your manipulation to the variable** and then

```
enemyhealth.setText("Enemy Health:" + enemyone_health);
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating the TextView try:

```
findViewById(R.id.PlayerHealth).invalidate(); // May not be necessary
findViewById(R.id.PlayerHealth).requestLayout();
```

Then do this again for enemyhealth after updating that TextField.